# Fragment Menu disappears upon rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, screen-rotation

I have a menu added by a fragment in onCreateOptionsMenu(). When the fragment first appears the appropriate icons appear in the ActionBar and Pressing the menu key or the overflow icon shows the remaining menus added by the fragment.

However upon rotating the screen (emulator or physical device) the fragment menus disappear.
Not all the menus disappear, the activity menus are visible in both rotations.

Rotating back does not make the menus reappear.

I've attempted to add in supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() but that doesn't seem to bring them back.

I'm pulling out my hair... The fragments and views reappear with all their glory and restored values. The menus appear to be setup correctly since the work as long as the screen is has not been rotated.

This is under 4.3 (both emulator and physical) and the support library ActionBar.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem.

I was not calling setHasOptionMenu(true) in the onCreate(). I was calling it only before adding the fragment.

It appears that the value is not part of the fragment state.